# Как объявить массив, если мы не знаем количество чисел?

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При объявлении массива

```
    int test;
    int i = 0;
    int [] arr;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Exit - 0");
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        test = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        arr[i] = test;
        i++;
    } while(test != 0);

    System.out.println(arr[5]);
```

Таким образом программа не работает: 
***java: variable arr might not have been initialized***

А если указать длину массива, то все работает нормально.

```
int [] arr = new int[200];
```

У меня возник вопрос, а если мы не знаем сколько чисел хочет ввести человек и программа без указания длины, просто не работает. Каким образом заставить её?

Comment: Мой ответ вам помог?

Answer (score 2):

В таких ситуациях вместо массива нужно использовать списки:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Exit - 0");
do {
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    int test = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    list.add(test);
} while(test != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();

...

a.add(x);
```

Comment: `List` абстрактный, нельзя создать его экземпляр.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, исправил.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия только все-таки наверное интерфейс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ согласен, но ведь интерфейс абстрактный)

Comment: @ИмяФамилия абстрактнее некуда